# Multiple self-content pages

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to migrate Polymer 1 application to Polymer 2. My application comprises one "main" page *index.html* and one static file "multiple.html".

"index.html" is the first page delivered to client. After users successfully log in to server via *index.html*, "index.html" creates the following tags inside itself:

```
<a href="/m/1" target="_blank">menu item 1</a>
<a href="/m/2" target="_blank">menu item 2</a>
<a href="/m/3" target="_blank">menu item 3</a>
```

After users click on *menu item N*, server sends over the same file *multiple.html*. Browser than calls function *document.URL* to get *1*, *2*, or *3* as request parameters for data from server to build pages of different contents from the same static file "multiple.html". As such, the browser might now opens one *main* page and several "instances" of pages spawned from static file *multiple.html*.

Here is my problem: Polymer 2 allows only one "main" page, which is supposed to be specified in file *bower.json*. How do I restructure my application so that I can run command

```
polymer build --js-minifiy --html-minify
```

and produce the correct compressed files, *index.html* and *multiple.html* in particular, in directory *build/default*?

**Edit** Please note that because files *index.html* and *multiple.html* share many files of custom elements, it is not a good idea to split this one application into two applications.

**Edit 2** Many thanks for your inputs! I did not make my question specific enough. I will follow the design pattern illustrated by [Polymer Shop](https://github.com/Polymer/shop) and try using Polymer element [app-route](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route).

Comment: did you try using a polymer.json? if it did not help can you maybe describe what is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a `polymer.json` file in the root of your app.

In there you can define multiple files.

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "fragments": [
    "multiple.html",
  ]
}
```

for more details see 
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-json

e.g. you can also provide the js minification and html minification there so you don't have to provide it on command line.